# Detecting File Changes in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Using the Source Control Explorer for TFS in Visual Studio, is there a way to detect local changes to files (or even new files in the directory hierarchy) that weren't first checked out?

We have a highly disconnected setup at my current client whereby accessing TFS means being on a specific VPN, which breaks connections to other things (such as internal database servers and any web access).  So any time a file needs to be modified we need to connect, check out, disconnect, which leads to what I feel is a derailing mental context switch for the developer (especially when working with a lot of files and not knowing ahead of time which ones are going to need to be modified).

We can just work locally and select "Overwrite" any time Visual Studio asks us what we want to do with various non-checked-out files.  But then is there a way to detect what files have been changed (or at least made writable) when we want to sync back with the server?

Or maybe I'm going about this all wrong?  Backing up a step, what's the ideal way to work on a solution that's bound to but disconnected from TFS source control?

Comment: Are you sure there's no way to set up the VPN better?  If it's a standard Windows VPN, for example (i.e., no 3rd party client), you can uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network" and it'll fix that kind of problem (let me know if you need more detail and I'll post it as an answer).

Comment: @Dan Puzey: I like this approach, but I'm not seeing that setting.  This should just be a standard Windows VPN (Windows 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since David's suggested this might work in his comment, here are the instructions for disabling the remote gateway on the VPN connection.  (admittedly this makes it a bit more of a "SuperUser" answer, even if the question was StackOverflow...)

- Open the "Network and Sharing Centre"
- Click "Change adapter settings" (on the left)
- Right-click your VPN connection & select "Properties"
- On the "Networking" tab, select the IP4 protocol ("Internet Protocol Version 4") and click Properties
- Click "Advanced"
- On the "IP settings" tab, untick "Use default gateway on remote network"
- Click "OK" on everything

I think you have to reconnect the VPN for this to take effect, but basically what this does is stops routing *all* network traffic through your VPN, and only routes through the stuff that it can't find on the regaular connection.  Hopefully that'll mean you can see both TFS and SQL at once!

Good luck ;-)

Comment: You're right, it's become more of a SuperUser answer, but it gets the job done for me at least based on the conditions in the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from doing a folder comparison, I don't know of any way to do this.

Have you tried "work offline"? When VS can't find TFS at startup, it asks if you want to work offline. When it gets back in touch, it looks for offline changes, and tries to sync them. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Intuitively that's how I would have thought it would work (though I'm not TFS expert), and maybe it's supposed to but there's something else wrong here.  For lack of a better description, Visual Studio just really doesn't like being disconnected from the TFS server.  It doesn't seem to track anything when offline.  (Nor does it even prompt me when opening the solution, it only prompts me regarding file write protection when saving individual files.)

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Honestly?  I don't know.  A team over in India manages it, and they're not very forthcoming on information or access.  I'm going to assume 2008, since they only recently started moving from VS2008 to VS2010.

Comment: @David: in Team Explorer, what is the name of your server? Does it end in "\DefaultCollection" or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

It's been so long that you've probably already figured this out and moved on, but I encountered the same problem and found a work-around solution for the immediate problem.

Microsoft's solution (Check out the files before your go offline) will work going forward, but to actually get your offline changes into TFS when you haven't checked out all the files (seriously, who's going to know exactly which files you are going to be working with in solution with 100's to 1000's of files), all you need to do is:

1. When you get back to the office, upload your changed files to your online solution ( I make a copy of my solution directory before I do anything).
2. Disconnect all network connections from your workstation; i.e., unplug your Ethernet cable, or turn off your WiFi.
3. Start VS2010 and open your online solution.
4. Wait about five minutes until VS2010 times-out trying to find your TFS server.
5. When VS asks you to use your solution in offline mode, click "Yes".
6. Exit VS.
7. Reconnect to your network; i.e., plug in your Ethernet cable or turn your WiFi back on.
8. Start up VS and open your online solution.
9. Open the Solution Explorer.
10. Select your solution in the solution explorer.
11. Press the "Go Online" button in the Solution Explorer's tool bar.
12. The "Go Online" dialog appears. You will see a list of all your changed files. You can right click on each one and compare it to the Latest Version on the TFS server.
13. Click OK.

Now, going forward, you can check out everything before you start working offline to avoid this hack.

IHTH

Comment: Wow, that is _quite_ the workaround.  And one that I dare say I would refuse to do on a regular basis, insisting otherwise that we fix the problems which led to the situation in the first place (the silly disconnected setup).  As you say, I've moved on (to a completely different job, in fact, and though we also use TFS it's considerably better managed and this isn't a problem).  But thanks :)